# Laravel using trait in a trait not working

Tags: php, laravel, traits

So i have a trait, let's name it `TraitTwo`
It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\Using1;
use App\Models\Using2;

trait TraitTwo
{
    public function MyFuncTwo() {
        code..
        code..
    }
}
```

I want to use this trait in another trait, let's name this one `TraitOne` It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App;
use App\Models\UsingOne;
use App\Models\UsingTwo;
use App\Models\UsingThree;
use App\Models\UsingFour;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\UsingFive;
use UsingSix;
use UsingSeven;

trait TraitOne
{
    use TraitTwo;
    public function MyFuncOne() {
        TraitTwo::MyFuncTwo();
    }
}
```

Except this is not working, I keep getting the following error:

> Trait 'App\Traits\TraitTwo' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I forgot the .php after the filename..

Comment: Wow, I was stuck on the same thing for ages, haha thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should reset composer cache after creating a Trait, in your console :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then, try again

Comment: Maybe this proves usefull for you..```"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },```